# connecting mongodb to c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, 10gen-csharp-driver

I use c# and asp.net mvc (visual studio 2015). When I try to connect mongodb to c#,this error appears:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoConfigurationException: The connection string 'mongodb:://localhost' is not valid.
```

and the error source is:

```
var client = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.bigdataconexionstrin);
```

this is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication5.Properties;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IMongoDatabase db1;
        public HomeController()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.bigdataconexionstrin);
            MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
            settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
            this.db1 = client.GetDatabase(Settings.Default.db);
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [the manual](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/), a valid connection string (with one host) is of the following format:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host[:port][/[database][?options]]
```

Judging from your error message, you are using `mongodb:://localhost`. Note that repeated colon, which makes this invalid. So you need to correct the connection string in your configuration.

That being said, directly after initializing the `MongoClient` you set up the `MongoClientSettings` which is an [alternative way](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient__ctor_1.htm) to specify the connection settings for the `MongoClient`. But you never use these settings to create the client. If you wanted to use them, your code should look like this:

```
MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
var client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

But then you don’t use the connection string from your settings. So you should decide which of these two ways of specifying the connection settings you want to use.

Comment: very good. I also did stop using connection string to connect mongodb.